# How to set SameSite LAX using JBOSS 7.4

Tags: jboss, undertow, samesite

We are currently using JBOSS 7.4 for functional testing. I've read on the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) that undertow version is 2.2.5
and according to the [undertow blog](https://undertow.io/blog/index.html)
that to configure the samesite cookie on a webapp, I have to added an **undertow-handlers.conf** file (located in the **WEB-INF folder**) which contains only the following line:

`path(/)->samesite-cookie(mode=Lax)`
but this is not working (I'll update with stacktrace later)

I tried different syntaxes but I still cannot start Jboss :

`path(/)->samesite-cookie(mode=Lax, cookie-pattern=*)` ---> `PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0`

`path(/)->samesite-cookie(mode="Lax", cookie-pattern="*")` --->

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000045: Error parsing predicated handler string no handler named samesite-cookie known handlers are [disallowed-methods, allowed-methods, buffer-request, jdbc-access-log, http-continue-accept, secure-cookie, access-log, mark-secure, response-rate-limit, canonical-path, response-code, disable-cache, ssl-headers, trace, blocking, url-decoding, error-file, access-control, redirect, set, ip-access-control, request-limit, resource, compress, restart, clear, byte-range, eager-form-parser, done, rewrite, forwarded, stuck-thread-detector, reverse-proxy, jvm-route, learning-push, dump-request, proxy-peer-address, resolve-local-name, header, store-response, path-separator, resolve-peer-name]:
path(/)->samesite-cookie(mode=\"Lax\", cookie-pattern=\"*\")
                        ^"}}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as none of the above is working.

Thank you.

Comment: "not working as expected" is nowhere as descriptive enough for people to help you.